# Get original hamming word without control bits

Tags: algorithm, error-detection

How can I get the original word without hamming encoding?

For example:
I've this hamming encoded word: 011001101100
How can I get back to the original word? correct ans is: 00111100

Comment: Note to all: the OP is using [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm). The original data is `00111100`. Parity bits are inserted at positions marked with an underscore giving `__0_011_1100`. The parity bits themselves are `0100` so the correct encoded word is `010001101100`. The encoded word in the question has a single bit error at bit position 3, so the error *can* be detected and corrected.

Comment: I know it's an obvious response, but you use the corresponding error correction algorithm.  You get the original word with Hamming **de**coding, a well-documented process -- usually documented with the encoding description.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding algorithm is described by [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm). The article contains a table that can be used to perform the decoding process by hand. Converting the decoding process to software is left as an exercise for the reader.

[image]

First, write the received code word along the bottom of the table. Then, for each row, compute the parity and write it into the column at the right. For example, for row `p8`, we want the parity of the five bits at the end of the code word, as indicated by the red X's. If there are an even number of 1 bits in the indicated positions, write a 0 in the right column, otherwise write a 1.

The resulting binary number in the right column (MSB on the bottom) indicates the bit position of the bit with an error. If the number is 0, then no bits have an error. In this example, the right column contains the number 3, so there's a bit error at bit position 3.

To complete the decoding, follow the steps below:

```
0110 0110 1100     the received code word
0100 0110 1100     flip the bit that has the error (bit 3 in this example)
__0_ 011_ 1100     remove the parity bits
```

and the remaining bits are `00111100`.